# internet sharing from a wifi-connected mac over ethernet to create second wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, mac, internet

I live in a building where our landlord functions as an ISP, which charges above-market rates for internet access. Therefore, I purchase internet from Xfinity instead, via a wifi hotspot. I access the internet through a Mac Mini, which is registered with Xfinity’s wifi network.

There are many answered questions about sharing internet between a Mac and a second device. But I could not find an answer to how to share internet between a Mac and many devices, using a wireless router connected to the Mac. It is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/909096/configure-router-to-receive-internet-connection-from-laptops-ethernet-port?rq=1), but using a Mac.

I tried connecting the Mac’s ethernet port to the WAN port of the router, and turning on Internet Sharing from the Mac’s wifi connection to ethernet. This did not work.

Is the router even needed here? I am wondering if a wireless adapter is all that is needed to create the second wifi network, but I am unsure if the Mac’s Internet Sharing capability allows it to share internet over its ethernet port with more than one other device at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear - so you may want to tidy it up in response to this post.

Short version - **You generally would not share the connection between the Mac and a second device - you would connect both the Mac and all the other devices to the WIFI hotspot.    The devices will be able to talk to each other and to the Internet - as a WIFI hotspot is acting as a wireless router.**

You would connect a WAN port to an ISP connection, not to a device on your network.  If your hotspot has a LAN port you cwould connect your local network to that.

I don't know anything about Xfinity - you may want to update your post with the model of WIFI hotspot you are using.

I also don't know where a router is coming into this.  It is likely unneeded here (unless your hotspot only shares over WIFI and you have devices you want to connect with Ethernet and you can convert the router to act like an AP client - ie convert WIFI to ethernet)

Comment: Connecting to the Xfinity hot spot requires my account credentials to log in, and I would like to set up a home wifi network with a password I manage. I would like guests to be able to connect to the wifi without giving them my Xfinity account credentials. It is not possible for me (or anyone) to physically connect directly to the Xfinity hotspot over ethernet, as they are located external to the building.

Comment: Basically, I would like the Mac to function as a gateway, and to be able to create a second wifi network separate from the Xfinity network. Because the Mac gets its internet connection over wifi (and not ethernet), my understanding is I cannot use the Mac’s internet sharing feature to create a wifi network directly, since its wifi card is already being used to connect to the Xfinity network. I understand this is not using the “routing” capabilities of the router, only its ability to create a wifi network. But I am unsure what the correct hardware I need is.

Comment: The Xfinity hot spot assigns me a public IP address. Each device connected directly to the wifi hot spot receives a different public IP address. Therefore, my understanding is the Xfinity hot spot is not acting as a wireless router.

Comment: (A router is a more generic term then you think.  Your hotspot is acting as a router.  This is largely irrelevant though).   I can't help you with turning your Mac into a router as I don't "do" Macs, but you may want to consider getting a  "WISP router".  This is a device that will act as a WIFI client to the XFINITY connection and as a router/wireless router for your local network - ie it will share your XFINITY connection/IP address among your devices.   You will be able to configure your own WIFI SSID (ie  Wireless network name) and password and share that with your devices.